# Eclipse PHP projects give error: "A cycle was detected in the build path of project"

Tags: php, eclipse, cyclic-reference

I have 3 php projects that depend on each other. They can't be grouped in one project because each of them has a different environment they execute in.

When I build it, I have no errors except this:

[image: 3x A cycle was detected in the build path of project]

Now I can find for Java how to disable errors on this type of error, but nothing for PHP. How can I turn this error into a a warning for PHP eclipse?

[image: Circular dependencies set to warning]
I have tried setting Preferences > Dynamic Languages > Cyclic warnings to warning, but after a clean and build the error persists.
After closing eclipse and restarting it, the error also persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What made eclipse wake up for me at last was moving the included projects up and down once.
I'm not sure what internals in eclipse this triggered, but this removed the cross and exchanged it for the yellow warning sign.

So set the error level for circular dependencies to Warning.
`Preferences > Dynamic Languages > Cyclic warnings`

On the `project > properties > PHP > Source Paths > Include Path > [tab Order]`
Move one of the two up or down, click apply, then move back, click apply again.

This removed the pesky error for me.

[image: Moving the projects up and then down]